# Make a span overlap an "overflow"

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a problem with my page. I am using a menu of icons on the left and it displays a `span` when I put the cursor on an icon. My list being a bit long, I want it to display a scrollbar if the window is smaller:

```
overflow-y: auto; 
overflow-x: hidden;
```

under `#navigationMenu`.

Doing so, the `span` hides under the scrollbar on the right. If you remove the overflow items, the `span` goes over and that is what I'd like to achieve. Unfortunately, if you remove the `overflow` items under `#navigationMenu`, the menu is unscrollable.

I've created a Fiddle about it for a better understanding:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2rLaaqL/3/

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 3%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  min-width: 2.5%;
  z-index: 10;
}
ul.navbar li {
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
ul.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigationMenu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 65px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#navigationMenu li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 20px;
}
#navigationMenu span {
  width: 0;
  left: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 39px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s;
  transition: 0.25s;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
#navigationMenu a {
  height: 39px;
  width: 38px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#navigationMenu a:hover span {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigationMenu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #9ddff5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #9ddff5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #9DDFF5;
}
/* Green Button */

#navigationMenu #testClass {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/34/AlthepalHappyface.svg/256px-AlthepalHappyface.svg.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
#navigationMenu #testClass:hover {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/34/AlthepalHappyface.svg/256px-AlthepalHappyface.svg.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
#navigationMenu #testClass span {
  background-color: #7da315;
  color: #3d4f0c;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigationMenu" class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 5</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 6</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="testClass" href="#">
      <span>Test 7</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<body>
  This is my body.
</body>
```

The "culprit" is `overflow`.

```
#navigationMenu {
   position: fixed;
   width: 65px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: why is width of `navigationMenu` 65px? `margin-left` of body is 150px

Comment: Simply to push back the body, otherwise it underlaps my menu. The wisth:65 is used to make the scrollbar not overlap my icons.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get child element "out" of `overflow: hidden` parent (which has some `position` other than `static` set so overflow takes effect) is to set `position` of the child to `fixed`:

https://jsfiddle.net/x2rLaaqL/4/

This won't work in most cases (more precisely in cases when parent is not `fixed` - then it could scroll "away" from its `fixed` children), but in your case, because parent *is* `fixed`, this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, I've tried that already. If you reduce your browser window enough to have a scroll bar in the menu and scroll down, check what it does when you put your cursor on an icon. :-/